# Reversing a linked list using nested while loops

Tags: c

I need some help.

I have this homework assignment due on Wednesday and the only thing I haven't been able to do is reverse my linked list. I have literally been working on this all day.

My professor hasn't told us any way to do this and doesn't allow us to email him questions so I'm kind of stuck.

He wants us to accomplish this by using nested while loops and pointers called front & back, and newhead.

Below is my code. Let me know if you have any questions and thanks in advance.

NOTE: Code is compiled in Code::Blocks using the GNU compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int random_number;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

typedef Node *Nodeptr;

void printout(Nodeptr);
void sum(Nodeptr);
void reverse(Nodeptr);

int main() {
    Nodeptr head = NULL;

    if ((head = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL)
        return 0;
    head->random_number = rand() % 50 + 50;
    head->next = NULL;

    Nodeptr here = head;
    Nodeptr newnode = NULL;
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        if ((newnode = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL)
            return 0;
        newnode->random_number = rand() % 50 + 50;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        here->next = newnode;
        here = here->next;
    }
    printout(head);
    sum(head);
    reverse(&head);
    printout(head);

    return 0;
}

void printout(Nodeptr head) {
    Nodeptr aux = head;
    int n = 0;
    while (aux != NULL) {
        printf("The value of node no. %d is %d \n", n, aux->random_number);
        aux = aux->next;
        n++;
    }
}

void sum(Nodeptr head) {
    Nodeptr aux = head;
    int n = 0, sum = 0;
    while (aux != NULL) {
        sum += aux->random_number;
        aux = aux->next;
        n++;
    }
    printf("The sum total of all nodes in this list is %d\n", sum);
}

void reverse(Nodeptr head) {
    Nodeptr newhead = head;
    Nodeptr back = NULL;
    Nodeptr front = NULL;

    while (back != NULL) {
        front->next = back;
        back = NULL;
        front = head->next;
        back = head;
        while (front != NULL) {
            front = newhead->next;
            newhead->next = back;
            back = newhead;
        }
        newhead = head;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a row of cards and the only change you can make is to swap two cards at a time, how can you reverse the row? Can you do that with two pointers?

Comment: What's really confusing me is the outer loop. My professor insists I need it and will deduct points from my assignment if I don't have it, but I'm not entirely sure why I need it.

Comment: What exactly does your professor insist? Did he specifically say that you need one loop inside another loop? Anyway, see if you can figure the cards thing out ^

Comment: Yes. He said that the inner loop should use the front and back pointers to go down the list, and the outer loop should set the front->next pointer to back, the back pointer to NULL, reset the front pointer to head->next and reset the back pointer to head.

Comment: When I asked for help and told him I was confused he just insisted this would be difficult and didn't answer any questions. It's not the best class.

Comment: OP, honestly, I must say, I agree with your professor's approach. It is important to think about this and figure it out independently. I remember being in the same position when my professor was teaching me about linked lists, and I remember probably spending 3 hours drawing and scrapping flowcharts, and then working through potential solutions step-by-step to see if they would actually function properly. I would highly encourage you to consider Ryan's card comparison. Once you figure out the basic method to answer his comparison, consider it abstractly, and finally consider how to code it.

Comment: @SpencerDoak: What I was going for wouldn’t involve a nested loop, though. It just seems like needless complexity (both code and time).

Comment: @Ryan: I agree 100%.  There is no need for 2 nested loops, a simple iteration suffices: picture the band of elephants from the Jungle book ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrQQZuLru9s ), each holding the tail of the previous one with its trunk... If you make each elephant turn 180 degrees and catch the tail of the next from the first to the last, and you have your list reversed, the last elephant being now the new leader.

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse a linked list:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E (odd numbered case)
E -> D -> C -> B -> A

A -> B -> C -> D (even numbered case)
D -> C -> B -> A
```

Do you see how the items have changed place? In the odd numbered case, A swapped places with E, B with D and C didn't move.

Now do you have some idea how to do it via a loop? The outer loop goes from the start of the list to the half-way point, the inner loop locates the matching item to swap them.

Definitely not the most efficient way to reverse a linked list, but I guess it's just a way to get you think more about the data structure.

The reverse() you posted didn't make sense, because the pointer values are incorrect. With back initialized to NULL, the while loop will not execute at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what API you teacher want you to use for `reverse`:

- The simplest one would take a `Node *` and return the new head pointer. You would invoke it from `main` as `head = reverse(head);`

Here is a simple implementation of this approach:

```
Node *reverse(Node *head) {
    Node *front = head;
    Node *newhead = NULL;
    while (front) {
        Node *back = front->next;
        front->next = newhead;
        newhead = front;
        front = back;
    }
    return newhead;
}
```

- An alternative API would have `reverse` take a pointer to the head pointer, hence a `Node **`, and update that to point to the reversed list.

Here is how it works:

```
void reverse(Node **headp) {
    Node *front = *headp;
    Node *newhead = NULL;
    while (front) {
        Node *back = front->next;
        front->next = newhead;
        newhead = front;
        front = back;
    }
    *headp = newhead;
}
```

Note that you do not need nested loops.

Note also that you should not hide pointers behind typedefs, it is bad practice, error prone and creates confusion for both the next reader and the original author.